# Python script(s) to retrieve Azure DevOps work-items (first IDs, then work-item data)

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops

My task is to build a solution to automate the retrieval of ADO work items for an entire Project (work items -> a file that can be consumed by a reporting tool) using the REST API.  I cannot use the normal interfaces because there is a character limit that limits the data to 3,000 characters per field.  Some of my fields have more characters than that.

I am building this in Python (VS Code).

So, I think I need to:

1. Retrieve the work item IDs
2. Put a loop together to iterate through the work-item IDs and pull the actual data, 200 at a time (the API has a limit of 200 IDs per call)
3. Store the data somewhere

What I can do so far (I will update this as we go!):

- Retrieve work-item data from a single ID.

---

So my next step is to figure out how to retrieve the full list of IDs.  Do any of you guys know how to do that?  I can do it in Postman but JUST for one Team.  I need to do it for the entire Project (probably upwards of 100 different Teams).

Thanks!

m00n

I have detailed what I have tried etc, above.  I hope this is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirement, you need to use Rest API to get the work item IDs list and then get the work item details via looping the work items.

To meet your requirements, you can use the [Wiql - Query By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query-by-wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) and Work [Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP)

You can add the related filters in the wiql rest api to get all related work item list.

Then we can loop the Work item list and send the work item ID to the Get Work item Rest API to get the details of the work item.

Here is an example:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://dev.azure.com/organization/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=5.1"

payload = json.dumps({
  "query": "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType]  <> ''"
})
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Basic Based64PAT',
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)



a = json.loads(response.text)
for i in a['workItems']:
     workitemid = i['id']
     print(workitemid)
     url1 = f"https://dev.azure.com//organization/project/_apis/wit/workitems/{workitemid}?api-version=7.1-preview.3"
     print(url1)
     response1 = requests.request("Get", url1, headers=headers, data='')
     print(response1.text)
```

**Note:** The Wiql - Query By Wiql Rest API will list all work items. The limit is 20000 work items.

Comment: @m00nface if the answer can help you, you can consider accepting it. Thanks